# How to enable self service group management for a user in azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I created a non privilege user in azure AD, when i sign in to https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com with that user only Applications & Profile tab is visible no Groups tab.  However whenever i assign that user any of the admin (Password, Service, Billing, etc ) roles the group option is available for self service.

I want to be able to request access to a specific group to get an access to SAAS application.  Please let me what need to be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Self-service group management is a [Premium feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/). Free and Basic licenses don't get it.